# GCE Instance containing multiple kernel builds occupying full space

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using a GCE instance (OS: ubuntu). I could see the disk space is full, Most of the space is occupied by kernel builds. Instance has different versions of kernel builds. I'm not sure how these were generated.

Has anyone encountered this issue. Any help in identifying and fixing the issue?

Here are the different versions but it's using 
3.19.0-66-generic #74~14.04.1-Ubuntu

```
root@bb-event-server-05:/lib/modules# ls -lrt
total 140
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Mar 15  2016 3.19.0-56-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr  6  2016 3.16.0-69-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr  6  2016 3.19.0-58-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr  9  2016 3.16.0-70-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 17  2016 3.16.0-71-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 17  2016 3.19.0-59-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 10  2016 3.16.0-73-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 10  2016 3.19.0-61-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 28  2016 3.16.0-76-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 28  2016 3.19.0-64-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 15  2016 3.16.0-77-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 15  2016 3.19.0-65-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug  9  2016 3.19.0-66-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  1 06:38 4.4.0-36-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Sep  1 06:39 3.19.0-68-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 20 06:54 4.4.0-38-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Sep 20 06:55 3.19.0-69-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 11 06:48 4.4.0-42-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 11 06:50 3.19.0-71-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 20 06:31 4.4.0-45-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 20 06:33 3.19.0-73-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 10 06:45 4.4.0-47-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 10 06:46 3.19.0-74-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 30 06:26 4.4.0-51-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 30 06:27 3.19.0-75-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  6 06:35 4.4.0-53-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec  6 06:37 3.19.0-77-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec 20 06:42 3.19.0-78-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 21 06:51 4.4.0-57-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 11 06:27 4.4.0-59-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 11 06:28 3.19.0-79-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  3 06:42 4.4.0-62-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb  3 06:43 3.19.0-80-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 21 06:40 4.4.0-63-generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 22 06:49 4.4.0-64-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to drop obsolete dependencies using `apt-get autoremove --purge`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and Debian leave old kernel versions by default on running systems after running upgrades.

You can find the kernel packages by running `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`. Then you can use `apt-get purge PACKAGE` to remove that package from your system. Replace PACKAGE with the package names you get from `dpkg`, except for the one that you are currently running.